# First integer of record contains clause for file was different from minimum

Tags: cobol, mainframe

I am trying to define a file in File section having record length of 300 and record format VB, but I am getting error as "First integer of record contains clause for file was different from minimum"

```
       FD  INPUT-FILE                                                  
E   THE FIRST INTEGER OF THE "RECORD CONTAINS" CLAUSE FOR FILE "INPUT-F   //Error msg
      ILE" WAS DIFFERENT FROM THE MINIMUM                                 //Error msg
           RECORDING MODE IS V                                         
           LABEL RECORDS ARE STANDARD                                  
           BLOCK CONTAINS 0 RECORDS                                    
           RECORD CONTAINS 30 TO 300 CHARACTERS                        
           DATA RECORD IS IN-02-RECORD.                                
                                                                       
       01  IN-02-RECORD.                                               
           05 IN-ALL           PIC X(30).                              
           05 IN-END           PIC X(270).
```

Answer (score 0):

Your definition has only one record which is fixed length which does not match to the variable-length `FD`.

You may want to use multiple fixed ones and/or a variable-length one:

single variable-length:

```
       FD  INPUT-FILE
           RECORDING MODE IS V                                         
           LABEL RECORDS ARE STANDARD                                  
           BLOCK CONTAINS 0 RECORDS                                    
           RECORD CONTAINS 30 TO 300 CHARACTERS                        
           DATA RECORD IS IN-02-RECORD.                                
                                                                       
       01  IN-02-RECORD.                                               
           05 IN-ALL           PIC X(30).                              
           05 IN-END           PIC X OCCURS 0 TO 270
                               DEPENDING ON some-var.
```

variable-length file in three possible lengths (removing the normally obsolete `DATA RECORD` clause):

```
       FD  INPUT-FILE
           RECORDING MODE IS V                                         
           LABEL RECORDS ARE STANDARD                                  
           BLOCK CONTAINS 0 RECORDS                                    
           RECORD CONTAINS 30 TO 300 CHARACTERS                        
           DATA RECORD IS IN-02-RECORD.                                
                                                                       
       01  IN-02-RECORD.
           05 IN-ALL           PIC X(30).
       01  IN-02-RECORD-B.
           05 IN-ALL-B         PIC X(30).
           05 IN-END           PIC X(270).
       01  IN-02-RECORD-C.
           05 IN-ALL-C         PIC X(30).
           05 IN-END-C         PIC X(70).
```